# passing a jquery object into a function

Tags: jquery

How would you do something like this:

```
somemethod($("#buttonelement"));

function(ele) {
  ele.click(function(event) { alert("hi"); });
}
```

in other words how do you pass in an element as a jquery object and register the click event.

Comment: What's not working about the code you posted?

Comment: the function doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 10):

Just like that...?

```
function someMethod(ele) {
    ele.click(function(event) {
        alert("hi");
    });
}

someMethod($("#buttonelement"));
```

The jQuery object is just like any other object in Javascript and can be passed to functions as normal.

Comment: Must agree with Green, does not work!
works with straight javascript tho:
var obj = document.getElementById('downpmt');
..then send obj to your function.

Comment: @HankCastello @ Green: if the above code "sometimes" does not work for you then you definitely have a problem somewhere else in your code. Claiming that the above function doesn't work "sometimes", and therefore isn't right, is voodoo programming.